# why does expressjs generate ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE for PUT when idle?

Tags: javascript, express, middleware, put

**Currently**

I have an express server that I am running locally to manage requests from a react client.

**Problem**

When my client is idle (I assume after the client PUT server actions previously), after about 3-5mins, error messages appear in the console logs.

*Error Message:*

[image]

This causes the next client PUT to the server to fail i.e. data is not saved.

**Request**

I don't have much experience with middleware management, so would appreciate some help on how to diagnose what may be causing this error.

Notes that may be helpful:

1. sometimes when the client makes too many PUTs to the server, the data fails to save, but there is no error message. I am forced to reload the page.

**Extract from Client - App.js**

```js
  saveData = data => {
    console.log("Submitting request to save...");
    fetch('/api/v1/savedata', {
      method: 'PUT',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data)
    })
    .then(console.log("Save complete!"));
  };
```

**Extract from Server.js:**

```js
// An api endpoint that saves data from the client
app.put('/api/v1/savedata', (req,res) => {
  console.log('Server received request to saveData');
  let options = {
    files: './data/save.json',
    changes: req.body
  }
  updateJsonFile(options);
});
```

Comment: I guess you are missing res.send() in put directive. Thus 3-5min is usually browser's timeout..

Comment: This was it. I needed to end the session either via .json() or send() or end(). Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you didn't sent any response in the API, use `res.send` or `res.json` like this:

```
app.put('/api/v1/savedata', (req,res) => {
  console.log('Server received request to saveData');
  let options = {
    files: './data/save.json',
    changes: req.body
  }
  updateJsonFile(options);
  res.json({data: data}) // if you want to send json response
  // Note: please don't send response object more than once
});
```

Comment: This was it. I needed to end the session either via .json() or send() or end(). Thank you.